# Byte array PAnsiChar in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, arrays

I have a byte array with some data...

```
CommandBytes : array of byte;
```

And I have a function of a VCL that sends command to a bluetooth printer.
The VCL function prototype is this

```
SendData(PAnsiChar, Cardinal);
```

"This method transmits bytes from the memory buffer into opened device"

How could I pass correctly the byte array to function to send command to printer?

I'm new to Delphi, I tried:

```
SendData(PAnsiChar(@CommandBytes[0]), SizeOf(CommandBytes));
```

but it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `SendData` function looks to be oddly designed. Unlike C and C++, Pascal has separate types for byte and char. So I'd normally expect `PAnsiChar` to be a null-terminated pointer. And a pointer to byte array to be declared as `PByte`. Is `SendData` defined by a third party? In which case I guess you have to fit in with it. But if it's your function then I'd change it to `PByte`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SizeOf()` on a dynamic array yields the size of a pointer. A dynamic array is a reference type that is represented as a pointer to the first element of the array. And hence `SizeOf()` returns the size of a pointer. And that's no use to you here.

You need to use `Length()` instead:

```
SendData(PAnsiChar(@CommandBytes[0]), Length(CommandBytes));
```

The [`Length()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Length) function returns the number of elements in an array.

What's more, I would probably simplify the way you cast to `PAnsiChar`. You can do it more concisely like this:

```
SendData(PAnsiChar(CommandBytes), Length(CommandBytes));
```

That's meaningful because `CommandBytes`, being a reference to a dynamic array, points to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The [`SizeOf(CommandBytes)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SizeOf) will return the size of a pointer.

Use [`Length(CommandBytes)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Length) to get the element count in the array, which in this case is the allocated buffer size, since SizeOf(byte) = 1.

Comment: `Length` returns element count rather than size. If just happens to be the same thing here because SizeOf(element) is 1.